# why does one of these definitions causes an issue and the other does not

Tags: typescript, functional-programming

```
(<T, Fn extends (x: T) => number>(f: Fn) => {
  const g = (x: T) => x;
  const h = (_: T) => 1;
  pipe(g, f);  // This gives a typing error.
  pipe(g, h);  // This works fine.
});
```

where pipe is defined like this

```
export type Func = (..._: any[]) => unknown;

export type Unary<Input, Output> = (_: Input) => Output;

export type Tail<L extends unknown[]> = L extends
  readonly [unknown, ...infer LTail] ? LTail
  : L;

type UnaryFn<A, R> = (a: A) => R;
type Arg<F> = F extends UnaryFn<infer A, unknown> ? A : never;
type Res<F> = F extends UnaryFn<any, infer R> ? R : never;

type ValidCompose<F1, F2> = Res<F1> extends (Arg<F2> | Promise<Arg<F2>>) ? F1
  : (arg: Arg<F1>) => Arg<F2>;

type ValidPipe<FS> = FS extends [infer F1, infer F2, ...infer Rest]
  ? [ValidCompose<F1, F2>, ...ValidPipe<[F2, ...Rest]>]
  : FS;

export const pipe = <Fs extends Func[]>(  ...fs: ValidPipe<Fs>) => null
```

I couldn't find any reason why the two statements would be treated differently, so I suspect it might have something to do with the implementation of generics.

However if you switch some definitions to this:

```
type Arg<F extends Func> = Parameters<F>[0];
type Res<F> = F extends UnaryFn<any, infer R> ? R : never;

type ValidCompose<F1 extends Func, F2 extends Func> = Res<F1> extends
  (Arg<F2> | Promise<Arg<F2>>) ? F1
  : (...arg: Parameters<F1>) => Arg<F2>;

type ValidPipe<FS extends Func[]> = FS extends
  [infer F1 extends Func, infer F2 extends Func, ...infer Rest extends Func[]]
  ? [ValidCompose<F1, F2>, ...ValidPipe<[F2, ...Rest]>]
  : FS;
```

Then suddenly it all works. Why?

Comment: @wonderflame the implementatino of reduce doesn't matter, because the code is never run, just the typing error is what I care about.

Comment: I meant it causes an error when I copy-paste the code. Ideally we shouldn't see any other error

Comment: @jcalz done ptal

Comment: @jcalz oh sorry I missed that. added now.

Comment: I've looked at this a bit and I have no idea what's going on.  Presumably somewhere the generic conditional type checking "gives up" in a different way.  I know the compiler doesn't really understand higher order generic conditional types, so it's not like the version that succeeds does so because it's verifying correctness.  Generic conditional type checking in TS is full of false positives and false negatives.  I won't even pretend to understand it well enough to try answering the question.